# Covert wide to long in sas when all the variable has the suffix needed

Tags: sas, transpose

I want the first wide dataset to be as the second long datafile, I have thought about using array, but considering I have 100 variables (the example only have 2), do I need 100 arrays?

Could you let me know how to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a double transpose. First transpose to a tall structure. Then split the name into the basename and time.  Then transpose again.  Here is untested code since no example data was provided (only photographs).

```
proc transpose data=have out=tall ;
  by id;
  var _numeric_;
run;
data fixed ;
   set tall ;
   time = scan(_name_,-1,'_');
   _name_ = substr(_name_,1,length(_name_)-length(time)-1);
run;
proc sort data=fixed ;
  by id time;
run;
proc transpose data=fixed out=want ;
  by id time ;
  id _name_;
  var col1;
run;
```